# Use Spring JpaRepository in test

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have Spring Boot application with configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled=true, prePostEnabled=true)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.site.data.repository")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.site.data.entity")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.*")
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

And in `resources` folder there is application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=...
spring.datasource.username=...
spring.datasource.password=...
spring.datasource.driverClassName=...
#...
```

**Problem:**

I try to make new class which will add some entries to database. I thought that the best solution is making a JUnit test class. So if anybody wants to feed my database he could simply run this specific test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebSecurityConfig.class)
public class DataFeeder {
    @Autowired
    MyRepository myRepository;

    @Test
    public void feedDB() {
        MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
        myRepository.saveAndFlush(entity);
    }
}
```

But this configuration doesn't work. Of course all repositories work great in project. But during running test I obtain messages that all tables don't exist. For example for SOME_TABLE:

```
Table "SOME_TABLE" not found; SQL statement:
```

I saw a lot of tutorials about how to test JpaRepository, but I don't want make test, which add some items and delete it after test end. I simply want save some data in database (but in @Test function)

What is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Try to use `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` instead of `@ContextConfiguration`

Comment: @Jens Unfortunately it doesn't change situation. I change log level and the first message is: `hibernate.properties not found`. So I suspect that Spring doesn't see application.properties in this test class. EDIT: no hibernate.properites is rather fine because in normal application start it occurs too.

Comment: @Jens I'm sorry. You are right. Your suggestion is correct. When I change  (correctly) to `@WebIntegrationTest` everything works fine. If you want, make answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Have added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` instead of `@ContextConfiguration`.
this is needed for Spring-boot application tests.